# java JodaTime remove seconds

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, iso8601

I am using JodaTime to create ISO 8601 String.

```
DateTime jodatime = new DateTime(2016, 04, 05, 23, 59, 59, 999, DateTimeZone.UTC);
String converted = jodatime.toDateTimeISO().toString();
```

Right now, I am getting the following:

```
2016-04-06T06:59:59.999Z
```

However, I want to truncate/remove seconds and milliseconds.

```
2016-04-05T23:59Z
```

Does anyone know how to do this with the least hacky way? 
And can anyone tell me if that shortened version of ISO8601 can be recognized by date parsing libraries?

Comment: Why are you relying on `toString()`? Create a formatter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way of formatting a Joda Time value is using a formatter. In this case, [the format you want is already available](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinute--), except for the Z:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute();
String text = formatter.print(value);
```

The `Z` is slightly tricky - I don't believe you can specify exactly what you want with a simple pattern (`DateTimeFormat.forPattern`) but you can use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYear(4, 9)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendMonthOfYear(2)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendDayOfMonth(2)
    .appendLiteral('T')
    .appendHourOfDay(2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendMinuteOfHour(2)
    .appendTimeZoneOffset("Z", true, 2, 4)
    .toFormatter()
    .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

I believe that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I used ` ISODateTimeFormatter.dateHourMinue().withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)`  but it is not showing 'Z' nor '+00:00"

Comment: Sorry, hadn't spotted the Z. If it's always UTC, you could just the `Z` at the end with string concatenation. Otherwise, build a new `DateTimeFormatter` - will edit to show that.

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry, laptop has just died... Will your values always be UTC? Would +00:00 be acceptable instead of Z? Will update answer when laptop is back up...

Comment: Z is preferred to +00:00.. But latter is also acceptable. I am looking for something like  `dateTimeNoMillis()` but also need to exclude second..

Comment: thank you very much. Initially, I wanted built-in method such as `dateTimeNoMillis()` so that I do not need to build format myself. But I cannot find one. I guess everyone is satisfied with precision to seconds. Builder is working very nice though, thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, just for who is trying this, the class name now is  "ISODateTimeFormat" instead of "ISODateTimeFormatter".
joda-time version 2.9.9

Comment: @luizMello: Just a typo - I'd linked to the right code. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove seconds and milliseconds of a joda DateTime instance like this easily.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DatiTime nowUpToMinuts = now.withMillisOfSecond(0).withSecondOfMinute(0);
```